# Middle Click Closes Application in "View All Windows"

Tags: operating-system, linux-mint, cinnamon

I'm trying to set up Fusuma with 3 fingers swipe up/down to display "View All Windows" (this window can be accessed by Ctrl+Alt+Down too). However, sometimes it's catching "Middle Button" right after the swipe.

This results in closing the application that the mouse is currently hovering over (in View All Windows). It's really annoying.

I've tried to look for settings to disable this option, but I couldn't find it. There was [a thread](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=246300) created awhile ago talking about this, but there was no real solution.

My questions are:

1. Is there an option to disable this "feature" in "View All Windows"? Perhaps I've missed something.
2. What's the name of this "View All Windows"? In case I want to recompile the codes, I need to know where to look. If you can send me to the codes that are responsible for this annoying feature, I'll really appreciate it.

What I don't want to do:
1. Disable middle button globally. I still want to use it.

My setups:

- Dell XPS 13
- Linux Mint 19 (Tara)

EDIT:
I think I've found where the code is. Here's the snippet of the responsible code in [workspace.js](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/blob/2499b0920ddbc86692f89cb54777486005add497/js/ui/workspace.js):

```
    _onButtonRelease: function(actor, event) {
    if ( event.get_button()==1 ) {
        this._selected = true;
        this.emit('activated', global.get_current_time());
        return true;
    }
    if (event.get_button()==2){
        this.emit('closed', global.get_current_time());
        return true;
    }
    if (event.get_button()==3){
        if (!this.menuCancelled) {
            this.emit('context-menu-requested');
        }
        this.menuCancelled = false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, I'm still lost on how to compile it. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is in:
`/usr/share/cinnamon/js/ui/workspace.js`

All I need to do is comment out this line:
`this.emit('closed', global.get_current_time());`

And restart Cinnamon with Ctrl + Alt + ESC.

It's working great now, woohoo!!